# Loading a Carousel from a Store in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: store, carousel, sencha-touch-2

Does anyone have a code example which would enable loading of a Sencha Touch 2 Carousel component from a Store (a JSON Store in my case)? I understand how to load a List which extends DataView, but Carousel appears to be a harder nut to crack since it does not extend DataView.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no built-in clean way to do this with the framework, however Ed Spencer (who works alongside me on Touch 2) wrote a blog post on how to do it:

http://web.archive.org/web/20121109164506/http://edspencer.net/2012/02/building-a-data-driven-image-carousel-with-sencha-touch-2.html

Comment: Brilliant. Thank Ed for me! His APOD app is almost exactly what I'm trying to do. Also I never knew the moon wobbled so much :)

Comment: Looks like edspencer.net is toast.

Comment: Yep, toast for sure. Thank god for the internet archive! [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20121109164506/http://edspencer.net/2012/02/building-a-data-driven-image-carousel-with-sencha-touch-2.html) [source code](https://github.com/edspencer/APOD)

Comment: Could you please help me: related to infinite carousel ;http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075538/how-to-make-carousel-infinite-in-sencha