# Sencha touch 2 - How to create dynamic carousel?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Sench Touch 2 - How to develop dynamic carousel in sencha touch 2? I want to show each element from the store as a separate card in the carousel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rdougan offered this as an answer. Looks good to me.

http://web.archive.org/web/20121109164506/http://edspencer.net/2012/02/building-a-data-driven-image-carousel-with-sencha-touch-2.html

Comment: Thank you grumplet . This solved my problem . But is there any other place to than to wite everything in the launch() . Like a listener that runs before the items in the view is rendered ?.

Comment: I'd guess the code for carousel listeners like 'activeitemchange' could be moved to a controller. About to tackle that myself...The [SenchaConDemo video](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/video/mvc-part-1) by Ed Spencer touches on this. [Code on github](https://github.com/edspencer/SenchaConDemo.git)

Comment: I've added some controller code which catches carousel events here:

Comment: Ext.define('MyApp.controller.CarouselController', {  

        extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',  
        config: { refs: {carousel: 'carousel'}},  
        init: function() { // add listeners here  
           this.control({ // to the carousel  
               activate: function(carousel, newItem) {   console.log(newItem.id);},
               activeitemchange: function(carousel, newItem) { console.log(newItem.id);},  
               deactivate: function(carousel, newItem, oldItem) {   console.log(oldItem.id);}  
}});}});

Comment: I have same problem, but could not get solution, How to create carousel with dynamic data. please visit:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075538/how-to-make-carousel-infinite-in-sencha

Answer (score 2):

Update:
There's a good answer now to [My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416057/loading-a-carousel-from-a-store-in-sencha-touch-2) quoting some Ed Spencer code. Also I notice that the new release candidate touchstyle example uses an infinite Carousel which is loaded from a Store.

Previously on this channel:
I asked this question yesterday at [Loading a Carousel from a Store in Sencha Touch 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416057/loading-a-carousel-from-a-store-in-sencha-touch-2). No answers yet, but I notice that the new release candidate offers horizontal scrolling of lists. So I'm hopeful this might give an equivalent to the Carousel which can be loaded from a Store.

Comment: but it doesnt look as cool as carousel .For dynamic carousel we have to give the value of 'items' a 'array' . And each element of that array should be of panel type.This is for creating a dynamic carousel. But i am stuck with where to initialize that array so that it gets executed before the carousel class is loaded. Thus my 'array' is in existence before carousel. You know any function where we can initialize 'array' . I am using MVC.

Comment: Agreed - carousel looks better.

Comment: Plz have a look at this.  http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?185343-Load-store-data-into-carousel-using-MVC . This helped me solve my problem .