# Break up HTML content into carousel items

Tags: javascript, css, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I would like to take some arbitrary HTML and display it in a carousel, showing a page at a time. For example, see how articles are laid out in the NY Times iPad app. I have achieved the column layout using the `-webkit-column-width` CSS property, and it works as expected if I add empty carousel items:

http://www.senchafiddle.com/#ea1RR

However, I need to figure out programmatically how many dummy carousel items to add, based on the number of columns. As far as I can tell, there is no way to find the width of the text, since the extra columns are overflow and don't affect the size of the element. Any help with this issue, or ideas on other ways I could achieve the same functionality, would be appreciated.

Comment: May be from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431699/sencha-touch-2-how-to-create-dynamic-carousel you borrow some ideas?

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: Thanks, but that is for showing elements of a store in a carousel. I don't have a store, I just have a string of HTML that I want to paginate and display in a carousel.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution can be adapted to fit your needs: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=196319

If you have problems start a senchafiddle so i can inspect your code