# Example of switching views with buttons for a carousel?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, carousel

Can any one point me to an example of changing views with buttons for a carousel ?

I would like the option to swipe or click to change views.

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431699/sencha-touch-2-how-to-create-dynamic-carousel

Comment: Or you can integrate : http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

Answer (score 2):

You've various ways to achieve it, you can either use [setActiveItem](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.carousel.Carousel-method-setActiveItem):

```
carousel.setActiveItem(1); // Move to the 2nd carousel's item.
```

or apply [next](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.carousel.Carousel-method-next) and [previous](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.carousel.Carousel-method-previous) method on your button `handler` to switch to the next and previous card of your carousel:

```
carousel.next();

carousel.previous();
```

Here is a demo: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#Ukg1N