# Create a Scrollable Data-view in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, sencha-touch

I am trying to create a horizontal scroll list which can be swiped left or right (something like Tinder, but with the option to come back to a previous content)

This is what I am trying to create: 
http://postimg.org/image/5jcurf1q1

This is what I have been able to get so far:
http://postimg.org/image/4o7h33w9h/

The problem is I am not able to make dataview item to stay within the boundaries of the mobile screen

What I have done till now to get this is:

Use a dataview

Set inline wrap to false

```
inline: {
    wrap: false
}
```

Set scrollable to 'horizontal'

```
scrollable: 'horizontal'
```

Set the following layout:

```
layout: {
    type : 'vbox',
    pack : 'center',
    align: 'stretch'
},
```

CSS set for the dataview:

```
.dataview-base {
    background-color: #cacacd;
}
```

CSS set for the dataview items:

```
.dataview-item {
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 5px solid #59535E;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #59535E;
    padding:20px;
    margin: 0px 20px 0px;
}
```

How can I achieve what I am trying to achieve ? I am pretty sure it has to do with the CSS of the dataview and the dataview items but I am not sure what ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is the complete Main.js view

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'main',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.DataView'
    ],
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'dataview',
                height: '100%',
                styleHtmlContent: true,
                inline: {
                    wrap: false
                },
                itemCls: 'dataview-item',
                baseCls: 'dataview-base',
                itemTpl: [
                    '<div class="arHeadline">',
                    '    {Headline}',
                    '</div>',
                    '<div class="arbyline">',
                    '    {Author}',
                    '</div>',
                    '<div class="arcontent">',
                    '    {Content}',
                    '</div>'
                ],
                store: 'Discovers',
                scrollable: 'horizontal',
                layout: {
                    type : 'vbox',
                    pack : 'center',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
            },
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                docked: 'top',
                title: 'Summary'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is using `carousel` instead of `dataview`. You can also load data into it: [Loading a Carousel from a Store in Sencha Touch 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416057/loading-a-carousel-from-a-store-in-sencha-touch-2)